# Will Ubuntu 13.10 boot if I enable compression on / which is a btrfs volume

Tags: boot, mount, filesystem, fstab, btrfs

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 on btrfs and the installer created the following fstab:

UUID=0eff8daf-5924-4a1f-922c-ec82ec594dc0 /          btrfs   defaults,subvol=@ 0   0
UUID=0eff8daf-5924-4a1f-922c-ec82ec594dc0 /home      btrfs   defaults,subvol=@home 0   0
UUID=babcf82e-ec47-4e02-b73a-8eed7b51908f none       swap    sw              0       0

If I enable compression on / and /home by adding 'compression=lzo' like this:

btrfs   defaults,compression=lzo,subvol=@ 0   0

will the system boot?

It says here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/btrfs#Adding_Filesystem_Compression

"NOTE: Grub2 in 11.04 can't read lzo compressed root so you'll need a /boot partition to use it."

But what about grub2 in 13.10?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can boot with compression on in a root btrfs filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in Ubuntu 12.04 "Precise Pangolin", see [bug #727535](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/727535) on Launchpad.